# Virtual Audio Cable (VAC)

Tags: audio, sound-card

I have had Virtual Audio Cable (VAC) before and it would make 1 line and I would add one more to geve me 2 lines. But now the program make two number 1lines. and when I make the number 2 line it give me two of them. I end up with two Line 1s and two Line 2s.

The programs That need them is Flex radio and a Digital program WSJT-X. with two 1s and two 2s they have trouble. I have to go into Device manager and delete one of each. then every thing works. Tell I restart computer. In the Virtual Audio Cable Panel (full version) it shows only one. tell I add the 2line, then it show 1&2 but in the Device Manager it has two of each.lol

Comment: Are they stereo lines? Maybe if you delete it and make them as mono? Alternative, remove the lines, then uninstall, reboot, reinstall, add the lines.

Comment: I well check for the stereo and set it to mono. As for removing them and uninstall and reboot, I have 3 times and every time I start the program it show me 1 line, but in device management there are two number 1s.